# Checking if MySQL Tables Exist and if not create them

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best way to check if tables exist in a MySQL DB? I was looking at a few code examples and have seen it done a couple of ways.

What I am trying to do is create tables like tag_tagnamehere so each tag has their own table with a link to the post/page ID.

So what I'm thinking is when people inset a list of TAGS I would loop through them and if the table is not found, create it and make and entry to that post/page ID.

Comment: "Each tag has their own table" sounds like a *bad* idea. Anything speaking against having one big table, and a "tag" column to tell them apart?

Comment: You should really re-think your solution. Creating tables instead of rows is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: Wouldn't using tables reduce query time instead of creating one big table?

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Maybe I didn't understand your design/table structure, although each tag shouldn't reside in its own table. You should have a table of tags, and a normalised scenario where other tables (if need be) define other tag attributes

Answer (score 1):

[Create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) has that built in.

`Create table Foo if not exists`

But you probably shouldn't do this. Note how its [done here](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/q/18270/) with a PostTag table

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name>...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about directly from a MySQL Query?

```
CREATE TABLE someTable IF NOT EXISTS
```